# Unexpected end of JSON ERROR in React Native package install

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, npm

I am trying to install `firebase` package in my React_native app

```
npm i --save firebase
```

The above command throws the following Error

```
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...5L/bQQbhWxIzUFW6GvaWs'
```

here is my app versions =>

```
"create-react-app": "^4.0.0",
"react-native": "^0.63.3",
"react-native-cli": "^2.0.1",
"react-scripts": "^4.0.0",
```

Comment: Seems like there was just a download error. Did you try again?

Comment: shouldn't it be yarn add @react-native-firebase/app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [docs](https://rnfirebase.io)

```
# Using npm
npm install --save @react-native-firebase/app

# Using Yarn
yarn add @react-native-firebase/app
```

not `npm install firebase`

I recommend you to go through the docs because there are different settings to iOS (pod files) and your android platform.